# How do I determine the time at which the largest number of simultaneously events occurred?

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting

Given a list of historical events, each of which ran for some number of seconds and has a non-unique start time, how can “best” I determine the range in time at which the maximal number of events was occurring? (In this case, for “best”, the dataset is stored in a SQL database, so I'm probably looking for something that balances a low number of queries with returning a small dataset to the client; there are potentially hundreds of events in the time interval under scrutiny.)

For example, given these events:

- Event 1 starts at 5, runs for 10
- Event 2 starts at 7, runs for 4
- Event 3 starts at 9, runs for 2

The most events are occurring from times 9-10 with 3 events occurring simultaneously.

One approach that comes to mind is iterating over the entire interval of time over which the events occur and, at each point, evaluating how many events were occurring there, then storing the maximum; but there surely must be some more efficient approach.

Comment: Probably, it would be better, if you'll provide `CREATE` and some example `INSERT`'s for your table

Comment: It would be useful to see the columns in the source data.

I think you are going to need to create another table and build some kind of scheduled roll up process to get a new set of data that is suitable for the reporting you're trying to create.

Comment: Get your time dimension worked out (second?)...select this and a count, group by the same time dimension you selected by, use having or top 1 order by count.  Can't do much else without an idea of what your tables look like.

Comment: How quantized are the possible start times and durations? In your example, all start times and durations are integers, which immediately suggests the use of a numbers table. This could still even work with more granular times, so long as there was some minimum quantum.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. I've asked the question before writing any code, so there actually isn't a schema yet – in fact, the schema will be dictated partially by whatever way makes it easy to access data in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "max" would occur when one of the events starts, you could do a self-join looking for the number of events in progress at that time:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(e1.StartDate), COUNT(e2.eventID) FROM event e1
INNER JOIN event e2 
  on e1.StartDate BETWEEN e2.StartDate 
                      AND DATEADD(second,e2.Duration,e2.StartDate)
GROUP BY e1.EventID
ORDER BY COUNT(e2.eventID) DESC
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer because I like getting an answer straight from my SQL query without having to do any further on-client processing. I also appreciate the observation that the peak number of events will be(gin) at the start point of an event; I'm not sure why that hadn't occurred to me, but that will come in useful elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.Take all your `event begin` and `event end` times and put in some struct like :

```
struct EventBeginOrEnd
{
bool begin; // True if event begin, false if end
int time;
}
```

Put all the events in a `List<EventBeginOrEnd> myEventList` and **sort** it.

2.Hold few counters :

- `CurrentEventCount` - counts how many events happening now.
- `MaxEventsCountSoFar` - counts the maximum events in one time measured till now.
- `TheMaxTime` - the time in which the maximum was measured.

3.iterate over `myEventList` and in each element check if he is begin or end, if begin increase `CurrentEventCount` otherwise decrease.

4.When `CurrentEventCount` is larger then `MaxEventsCountSoFar` update like this :

```
MaxEventsCountSoFar=MaxEventsCountSoFar;
TheMaxTime=currentElement.time;
```

Notice that this allows you to use floating point for time and not only int, because you are not iterating over time but over the events you have.

The complexity is `O(n*Log(n))` because of the sort.